# Which exactly DNS record does Let's Encrypt use to perform DNS-01 challenge validation?

Tags: bind, lets-encrypt

I have some SMTP servers (and others) which live behind the NAT and it is infeasible to configure DNAT for HTTP or reverse proxies for them. This means, HTTP-01 and TLS-ALPN-01 are unavailable, so [DNS-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge) is a natural choice for this case.

For other system I expected to have a wildcard certificate, again it is possible to validate only using DNS-01 challenge.

So I configured everything using `certbot-dns-rfc2136` plugin, according to the [documentation](https://certbot-dns-rfc2136.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I generated a key, configured an update policy in BIND to allow it to update the record `_acme-challenge.example.net`. (Actually I have the generic policy which allows a key `<name>.example.net` to update the any record with the same name, so this key may update not only `TXT` record.)

The following script works as intended (creates the record):

```bash
nsupdate -k dns-01.key -v << END
server 192.0.2.1
zone example.net
update add _acme-challenge.example.net 60 TXT "abrakadabra"
send
END
```

(the key `_acme-challenge.example.net` is stored in the file `dns-01.key`).

Then I removed this abrakadabra record and put this key into plugin credentials file.

```ini
dns_rfc2136_server = 192.0.2.1
dns_rfc2136_port = 53
dns_rfc2136_name = _acme-challenge.example.net
dns_rfc2136_secret = <some base64 string>
dns_rfc2136_algorithm = HMAC-SHA256
```

The DNS-01 challenge for the wildcard `*.example.net` worked successfully:

```bash
# certbot certonly --dns-rfc2136 --dns-rfc2136-credentials /path/to/credentials/file.ini -d *.example.net --test-cert
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-rfc2136, Installer None
Requesting a certificate for *.example.net

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem
   Your certificate will expire on 2022-09-05. To obtain a new or
   tweaked version of this certificate in the future, simply run
   certbot again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your
   certificates, run "certbot renew"
```

If I request a certificate for a single root domain (`... -d example.net`), it also works.

The problem is, the same credentials don't work for subdomain names (`... -d www.example.net`):

```bash
# certbot certonly --dns-rfc2136 --dns-rfc2136-credentials /path/to/credentials/file.ini -d www.example.net --test-cert
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-rfc2136, Installer None
Requesting a certificate for www.example.net
Performing the following challenges:
dns-01 challenge for www.example.net
Cleaning up challenges
Encountered exception during recovery: certbot.errors.PluginError: Received response from server: REFUSED
Received response from server: REFUSED
```

Examining the debug log:

```
...
2022-06-07 11:35:38,275:DEBUG:certbot_dns_rfc2136._internal.dns_rfc2136:No authoritative SOA record found for _acme-challenge.www.example.net
2022-06-07 11:35:38,276:DEBUG:certbot_dns_rfc2136._internal.dns_rfc2136:No authoritative SOA record found for www.example.net
2022-06-07 11:35:38,277:DEBUG:certbot_dns_rfc2136._internal.dns_rfc2136:Received authoritative SOA response for example.net
2022-06-07 11:35:38,279:ERROR:certbot._internal.error_handler:Encountered exception during recovery: certbot.errors.PluginError: Received response from server: REFUSED
2022-06-07 11:35:38,280:DEBUG:certbot._internal.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

I also tested the same thing with another DNS key, which is permitted to create any records within the zone. The same command worked with this key, which could only mean the `certbot-dns-rfc2136` plugin does not try to create `_acme-challenge.example.net`, and it uses another record instead, `_acme-challenge.www.example.net`. I confirmed this with the DNS request while waiting for DNS propagation, and also by looking into DNS server log. In this case the refusal was expected, because the former restricted key is only allowed to change `_acme-challenge.example.net` and not `_acme-challenge.www.example.net`.

But why it used a record name which I did not expected? Where is that covered in the documentation? I understand it like that `_acme-challenge.example.net` should be used for validating `example.net`, `*.example.net` and `<name>.example.net` for any `<name>`, this is given in the second usage example on the documentation page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which exactly DNS record does Let's Encrypt use to perform DNS-01 challenge validation?

`dns-01` validation is detailed in the RFC on ACME, aka [RFC 8555 "Automatic Certificate Management Environment (ACME)"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8555)

It states:

> 8.4.  DNS Challenge
>
> When the identifier being validated is a domain name, the client
> can    prove control of that domain by provisioning a TXT resource
> record    containing a designated value for a specific validation
> domain name.

and

> The record provisioned to the DNS contains the base64url encoding
> of    this digest.  The client constructs the validation domain name
> by    prepending the label "_acme-challenge" to the domain name being
> validated, then provisions a TXT record with the digest value under
> that name.  For example, if the domain name being validated is
> "www.example.org", then the client would provision the following DNS
> record:
>
> _acme-challenge.www.example.org. 300 IN TXT "gfj9Xq...Rg85nM"

The CABForum guidelines, as followed by all public CAs, also states:

> 3.2.2.4.7 DNS Change
>
> Confirming the Applicant's control over the FQDN by confirming the
> presence of a Random Value or Request Token for either in a DNS CNAME,
> TXT or CAA record for either 1) an Authorization Domain Name; or 2) an
> Authorization Domain Name that is prefixed with a Domain Label that
> begins with an underscore character.

with the following added important information:

> Note: Once the FQDN has been validated using this method, the CA MAY
> also issue Certificates for other FQDNs that end with all the Domain
> Labels of the validated FQDN. This method is suitable for validating
> Wildcard Domain Names.

Let's Encrypt own documentation is at https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/

> DNS-01 challenge
>
> This challenge asks you to prove that you control the DNS for your
> domain name by putting a specific value in a TXT record under that
> domain name.

Back to your question, you state:

> But why it used a record name which I did not expected?

If you try to validate the name `www.example.net`, per all the above, the `TXT` record has to be on `_acme-challenge.www.example.net`.

> I understand it like that _acme-challenge.example.net should be used for validating example.net, *.example.net and .example.net for any , this is given in the second usage example on the documentation page.

First, which documentation page you state?
Second, no, in general, each name has to have its validation token.
The wildcard `*.example.net` will also need a specific separate TXT record, on name `example.net` but with different value than the `TXT` record on `example.net` for the name `example.net` (as in certificates, name `*.example.com` will NOT cover `example.net` so the certificate needs to have both listed, and hence both need to be validated, to be valid for both).

Comment: I meant plugin's documentation: https://certbot-dns-rfc2136.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ . They configure the key which is only able to update `_acme-challenge.example.com. txt` and second example is intended to issue a certificate for both www.example.org and example.org, but using only that key. Essentially I tried to replicate this setup. RFC8555 section 8.4 explains the situation clearly; I did not knew it exists, because there are no references to that RFC on challenges page. // I am talking not about verification tokens, but for DNS RR names where those tokens should be placed.

Comment: "I am talking not about verification tokens, but for DNS RR names where those tokens should be placed." I still don't understand why you have this question when the documentation clearly says: "The client constructs the validation domain name by prepending the label "_acme-challenge" to the domain name being validated," (and removing the `*` if a wildcard).

Comment: "They configure the key which is only able to update _acme-challenge.example.com. txt" Where do you see that? The configuration does not list any specific name. It is up to server configuration (the nameserver) to decide which TSIG key can change which names. The TSIG key name is not related to the records name. A configuration example is given with the clear note: "This configuration limits the scope of the TSIG key to just be able to add and remove TXT records for one specific host for the purpose of completing the dns-01 challenge." So yes, you need to change that to update other names...

Comment: They set up pretty tight update policy for the `keyname.`, seen in their [BIND configuration example](https://certbot-dns-rfc2136.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#sample-bind-configuration). This policy will allow the key to only update `_acme-challenge.example.com TXT` record and nothing else. And yet they have [an example](https://certbot-dns-rfc2136.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#id2) which suggests to use that also for www.example.com. There is nothing said on the fact that for www we should extend the policy, as @HåkanLindqvist suggested in his answer.

Comment: "There is nothing said on the fact that for www we should extend the policy," I completely disagree. There is a specific note telling you the configuration given is ONLY for the name given. From that, I think the natural consequence is that if you want the configuration of the nameserver to work for other names to validate, hence records to create, you have to change the nameserver configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Patrick provides good background, but as a more direct take at the problem:

The example configuration in the certbot documentation has this update policy:

```
 update-policy {
      grant keyname. name _acme-challenge.example.com. txt;
 };
```

which allows the DNS-01 challenge to work for *exactly* the name `example.com`.

However, in your command line you specified `-d www.example.net`.

If you want a cert for `www.example.com` you need to adapt the example policy to reflect this.
For example, you want both `example.com` and `www.example.com` (quite likely) you need to allow both in the policy.

Eg something like this:

```
 update-policy {
      grant keyname. name _acme-challenge.example.com. txt;
      grant keyname. name _acme-challenge.www.example.com. txt;
 };
```

Comment: The [second example](https://certbot-dns-rfc2136.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#id2) in that documentation suggests it should work for www.example.com too. This is what I tried to replicate. I consider now that's the bug in the plugin documentation.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Indeed, I think the problem is limited to how the certbot documentation could do with some clarification regarding what that example actually allows, especially as it does not match the example commands.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov "I consider now that's the bug in the plugin documentation.". On the contrary I think you read too much into it. The two sets are separate. First you have examples how to run `certbot` then examples of DNS configuration needed, which clearly states the example given is only for the name given. It does not state anywhere the DNS configuration example is directly mapping to previous certbot commands examples.

Comment: Examples should be consistent and explained, else they are misleading. This thing was not consistent and this was not explained.

Comment: How is this not explaining: "This configuration limits the scope of the TSIG key to just be able to add and remove TXT records for one specific host for the purpose of completing the dns-01 challenge.". **one specific host**. It can't be more clearly explained in my view.

Comment: Could I please get clarity: `grant keyname. name _acme-challenge.example.com. txt` is *exactly* what would be in the record, right? It's not like "`keyname.`" or "`name`" stand for something that could be "`s0M37ONgk39y`"; only "`example.com`" would change, right? That's what it looks like after reading this: https://flylib.com/books/en/2.684.1/allowing_dynamic_updates.html

Comment: @Jesseיִשַׁי *keyname* is the name of the TSIG key

Comment: Do you know how to obtain only that though the cli? Or is that a separate question?

Comment: @Jesseיִשַׁי If you don't already have a key, use `tsig-keygen keynamegoeshere` to create one that you can put into your config and then reference by name.